# Where can i find the ext folder of openjdk?

Tags: java

i need to put a jar in the ext folder of my java installation to [install an extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html).
But somehow i am not able to locate this folder.

I am using openjdk 6 under crunchbang linux.
Can anybody help me out.

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a find command in a console

```
 find / -name "your key word"
```

in your case key may be java , openjdk or ext etc